# How do I get this Mac OS X exposé behavior?

Tags: compiz, plugins, macosx

In Mac os x, I can move all windows to the nearest corner by hitting F11 key.
I'm just wondering if there is a compiz plugin works like that.

I know that there is Scale plugin already. But all that I want is something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktTNcj0fAM4#t=3m40s).

You'll see, press a key and all windows fly off to nearest corner so I can drag/drop file or do something else on my desktop, then press the key again and all windows fly back.

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise [here is a link](http://www.howtogeek.com/112974/how-to-customize-ubuntu-with-ubuntu-tweak/) to do exactly what u're asking for.
After installation you go to *Tweaks* -> *Workspace* then you choose what event each corner triggers

Comment: It would be best to add information on how to install Ubuntu Tweak right in your answer. External links sometimes go dead. Also including the link and crediting the source, as you have done, is always a good, too. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for that **scale plugin**. Take a look for [that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=si1nXxWh3H0).

Comment: I know that there is Scale plugin already. But all that I want is something like this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktTNcj0fAM4. Skip to 3:40 and you'll see, I can press a key and all windows fly off to nearest corner then I can drag/drop file or do something on my desktop.

Comment: Oh.. so you can do this with `CTRL+WINDOWS+D` (you also have the option to set an individual keyboard shortcut in CCSM -> General Settings -> Key bindings -> Show desktop).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Skippy-XD`](http://code.google.com/p/skippy-xd/) for this. It is a full-screen task-switcher for X11 similar to Mac OS X's Exposé feature. To install latest development packages (recommended), use the [Skippy-XD PPA (daily)](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd-daily).

If you use `Xfce`, you can easily bind `skippy-xd` command to `Alt + Tab` in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`. For other DEs it should work similarly.

Comment: old and buggy now, deb version doesn't allow to select on release, ppa version is taking over the screen and won't quit unless all windows are closed with Alt-f4