# Is there a way to generate the gnome3 effect when pressing the super key on xfce

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, unity-dash, xfce

I've switched to xfce from gnome3. Mainly to experiment. I find the super key effect on gnome shell really useful. Both the showing all windows and the application finder are convenient. Is there a way to achieve this on xfce? (xubuntu 12.10).

*Edit:*
I'm using Gala windows manager.

Comment: No. XFCE does not have those kind of effects. For the Show all Windows effect, you can either use Compiz and use the Exposé-like effect or use Gala for the same purpose and replace XFWM4. The Application overview is unique to Gnome Shell only, you may use Synapse if you don't want to dig through the Menus.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I have gala install. Where can I configure it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have a dash-like search under Xfce?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247408/how-can-i-have-a-dash-like-search-under-xfce)

Answer (score 2):

I actually used Xfce with gala for a while. To configure the hot corner you must install dconf-editor.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then navigate to org,pantheon,desktop,gala and behavior I believe

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your question is mostly about having a Gnome Shell dash under Xfce.

Several solutions are suggested in this question: [How can I have a dash-like search under Xfce?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247408/how-can-i-have-a-dash-like-search-under-xfce/404721#404721). For example you can use `xfce4-whiskermenu` or `xfdashboard`.

For the Exposé-like effect, see: [How do I get this Mac OS X exposé behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138334/how-do-i-get-this-mac-os-x-expose-behavior/405250#405250). You can use `Skippy-XD` to achieve that.