# Compiz like XFCE application switcher

Tags: xfce

Is it possible to have an application switcher in XFCE that looks like Unity without using Compiz?

It's very useful when <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> bring the window to front and we can see what we have in there.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're looking for either of the following two:

- [How can I have a dash-like search under Xfce?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247408/how-can-i-have-a-dash-like-search-under-xfce/404721#404721)
- [How do I get this Mac OS X exposé behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138334/how-do-i-get-this-mac-os-x-expose-behavior/405250#405250)